# Reaching inside arrays within an arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Hey guys i have an issue which i can't seem to find an answer to.

So when i started accessing the array that i need.i did a `print_r(products['options'])`
i got arrays that are from 0 to 3

so i got inside the array that i needed which is number 2 `print_r(products['options'][2])`

this printed out the options that i needed which are

> Array ( [product_option_id] => 263 [option_id] => 16 [name] => Place
>   [type] => checkbox [option_value] => Array ( [0] => Array (
>   [product_option_value_id] => 99 [option_value_id] => 109 [name] =>
>   Iceland [image] => [quantity] => 0 [subtract] => 0 [price] => 0.0000
>   [price_prefix] => + [weight] => 0.00000000 [weight_prefix] => + ) )
>   [required] => 0 )

How do i acces the 2-nd array here? which is this:

> [0] => Array ( [product_option_value_id] => 99 [option_value_id] =>
>   109 [name] => Iceland [image] => [quantity] => 0 [subtract] => 0
>   [price] => 0.0000 [price_prefix] => + [weight] => 0.00000000
>   [weight_prefix] => + ) ) [required] => 0 )

If i try to acces it like this: `print_r(products['options'][2][0])`

I get an error `Notice: Undefined offset: 0`. Which i assume it just cant find the array 0.

The end goal here is to dig down and get `[name] => Iceland`

if i access it like this  `print_r(products['options'][2][0]['name'])` i get the first variable inside the array that is `[name] => Place`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print_r(products['options'][2]['option_value'][0]['name'])
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you,that worked perfectly

Comment: so the issue here was that option_value is the array that holds the other values that i needed?

Comment: Correct, you just missed this array key.